# How to find index of list item in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to find an `item index` by searching a `list`. Does anybody know how to do that?

I see there is `list.StartIndex` and `list.EndIndex` but I want something like python's `list.index("text")`.

Answer (score 932, accepted):

As swift is in some regards more functional than object-oriented (and Arrays are structs, not objects), use the function "find" to operate on the array, which returns an optional value, so be prepared to handle a nil value:

```
let arr:Array = ["a","b","c"]
find(arr, "c")!              // 2
find(arr, "d")               // nil
```

Use `firstIndex` and `lastIndex` - depending on whether you are looking for the first or last index of the item:

```
let arr = ["a","b","c","a"]

let indexOfA = arr.firstIndex(of: "a") // 0
let indexOfB = arr.lastIndex(of: "a") // 3
```

Comment: Where did you learn about the find function? I can't seem to find any documentation of "find" or any other global functions

Comment: Coming from the OOP world, how am I supposed to find this kind of free floating functions?

Comment: can also be used as `Swift.find(arr, "some value")` without the import.

Comment: Johannes and @Rudolf - use Dash.app. It's an OS X app for browsing documentation. It has a language reference for Swift that has a list of all the free floating functions. Easy to filter and search. Can't live without it.

Comment: @BjornTipling Too bad Apple can't make a usable documentation browser.

Comment: FYI: If you're using `indexOf` on an array of structs you defined yourself, your struct has to comply with the `Equatable` protocol.

Comment: Just as a note - in Swift2, there appears to be no special work needed to use this.

Comment: When searching Swift 3 arrays which contain instances of `NSObject` with the `index(of:)` method, the old `-isEqual:` method is used for comparison. In a test project I found that the `==` operator is not invoked. Quite surprising. Examples using strings do work though.

Comment: `arr.index(of: "element")` is not available in Swift 3

Comment: swift 3 example is wrong. index(of:) function not exists in swift 3.

Comment: @sschuth what does item.foo refers to?

Comment: All the answers are assuming object "equality" is used and not object "identity". to use these methods you MUST know and assume the object is of type "String" and use string comparison for finding a match. For that - if you have 3 objects with the value "a" you will always find only the first. The original question was about looking for an actual object. not an object equal to it.

Comment: If you're dealing with class types, you can do `arr.index(where: { $0 === target })`

Comment: @sschuth you may want to update for Swift 4.1 too :)

Comment: Can we delete the Swift 2 stuff? It's traumatic to see.

Comment: Swift 4.2, firstIndex(of:) returns optional integer which is supposed to be used with "if let".

Comment: what is there is one more "a" in between ? how to get that index?

Answer (score 270):

tl;dr:

For classes, you might be looking for:

```swift
let index = someArray.firstIndex{$0 === someObject}
```

---

Full answer:

I think it's worth mentioning that with reference types (`class`) you might want to perform an *identity* comparison, in which case you just need to use the `===` identity operator in the predicate closure:

Swift 5, Swift 4.2:

```swift
let person1 = Person(name: "John")
let person2 = Person(name: "Sue")
let person3 = Person(name: "Maria")
let person4 = Person(name: "Loner")

let people = [person1, person2, person3]

let indexOfPerson1 = people.firstIndex{$0 === person1} // 0
let indexOfPerson2 = people.firstIndex{$0 === person2} // 1
let indexOfPerson3 = people.firstIndex{$0 === person3} // 2
let indexOfPerson4 = people.firstIndex{$0 === person4} // nil
```

Note that the above syntax uses trailing closures syntax, and is equivalent to:

```swift
let indexOfPerson1 = people.firstIndex(where: {$0 === person1})
```

Swift 4 / Swift 3 - the function used to be called `index`

Swift 2 - the function used to be called `indexOf`

* Note the relevant and useful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift/32923407#comment60202729_32923407) by [paulbailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481742/paulbailey) about `class` types that implement `Equatable`, where you need to consider whether you should be comparing using `===` (*identity* operator) or `==` (*equality* operator). If you decide to match using `==`, then you can simply use the method suggested by others (`people.firstIndex(of: person1)`).

Comment: This is a useful post for those wondering why .indexOf(x) doesn't work - this solution is unexpected but perfectly obvious in retrospect.

Comment: Thanks so much for this but it's not obvious to me at all. I looked at the documentation and I really don't understand why would I need a predicate closure when using indexOf on a reference type? It feels like indexOf should already be able to handle reference types on its own. It should know that it's a reference type and not a value type.

Comment: If `Person` implemented the `Equatable` protocol, this wouldn't be needed.

Comment: i'm receiving: `Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Post'` , `Post` is my struct... any idea?

Comment: @DavidSeek, `structs` (and `enums`) are value types, not reference types. Only reference types (e.g `class`) have identity comparison logic (`===`). Check out the other answers for what to do with `structs` (basically you simply use the `array.index(of: myStruct)`, making sure type of `myStruct` conforms to `Equatable` (`==`)).

Comment: thank you @NikolaySuvandzhiev i have already learned that and am having my structs equatable :) but thank you for the explanation

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer as it works for both simple array and array of object.

Comment: very helpful, firstIndex gives the expected result!

Answer (score 90):

You can `filter` an array with a closure:

```
var myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var filtered = myList.filter { $0 == 3 }  // <= returns [3]
```

And you can count an array:

```
filtered.count // <= returns 1
```

So you can determine *if* an array includes your element by combining these:

```
myList.filter { $0 == 3 }.count > 0  // <= returns true if the array includes 3
```

If you want to find the position, I don't see fancy way, but you can certainly do it like this:

```
var found: Int?  // <= will hold the index if it was found, or else will be nil
for i in (0..x.count) {
    if x[i] == 3 {
        found = i
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

While we're at it, for a fun exercise let's extend `Array` to have a `find` method:

```
extension Array {
    func find(includedElement: T -> Bool) -> Int? {
        for (idx, element) in enumerate(self) {
            if includedElement(element) {
                return idx
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now we can do this:

```
myList.find { $0 == 3 }
// returns the index position of 3 or nil if not found
```

Comment: For funsies I added another example where I extend the builtin `Array` to have a `find` method that does what you want. I don't know yet if this is a good practice, but it is a neat experiment.

Comment: Just want to point out, that you should use ++idx as per docs: "Unless you need the specific behavior of i++, it is recommended that you use ++i and --i in all cases, because they have the typical expected behavior of modifying i and returning the result."

Comment: Good call. As you were posting this I was revising it to use `enumerate` so it no longer applies, but you're absolutely right.

Comment: Yea, I remembered noticing it in one of the examples when I was going through.  Trying to set myself in the habit now :)

Comment: Check out the `find` global function. You can use it like this `var array = ["blue"]; var index = find(array, "blue");`

Comment: where would I put the array extension if I want to use it in multiple files?

Comment: For this to work under Swift 2 / XCode 7 you need to modify it as follows.  Replace (includedElement: T -> Bool) with (includedElement: Element -> Bool) and change enumerate(self) to self.enumerate

Answer (score 51):

### Swift 5

```
func firstIndex(of element: Element) -> Int?

var alphabets = ["A", "B", "E", "D"]
```

Example1

```
let index = alphabets.firstIndex(where: {$0 == "A"})
```

Example2

```
if let i = alphabets.firstIndex(of: "E") {
    alphabets[i] = "C" // i is the index
}
print(alphabets)
// Prints "["A", "B", "C", "D"]"
```

Comment: The `where` version has this signature:
`func firstIndex(where: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int?`

And, since firstIndex has a trailing closure you could write for Example 1: 
`let index = alphabets.firstIndex { $0 == "A" }`  :-)

Answer (score 32):

While `indexOf()` works perfectly, **it only returns one index.**

I was looking for an elegant way to get an array of indexes for elements which satisfy some condition.

Here is how it can be done:

**Swift 3:**

```
let array = ["apple", "dog", "log"]

let indexes = array.enumerated().filter {
    $0.element.contains("og")
    }.map{$0.offset}

print(indexes)
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let array = ["apple", "dog", "log"]

let indexes = array.enumerate().filter {
    $0.element.containsString("og")
    }.map{$0.index}

print(indexes)
```

Comment: Be careful when using this on subsequences, offset it is not the same as an index. Not all collections indices starts from zero. Note that this would only work with `Equatable` elements. `let indices = array.indices.filter { array[$0].contains("og") }` or using zip `let indices = zip(array.indices, array).filter { $1.contains("og") }.map(\.0)`

Answer (score 21):

In Swift 4, the [firstIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex) method can be used. An example of using the `==` equality operator to find an object in an array by its `id`:

```
let index = array.firstIndex{ $0.id == object.id }
```

- note this solution avoids your code needing to conform to the [Equitable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) as we're comparing the property and not the entire object

Also, a note about `==` vs `===` since many of the answers posted so far have differed in their usage:

- `==` is the equality operator. It checks if values are equal.
- `===` is the identity operator. It checks whether two instances of a class point to the same memory. This is different from equality, because two objects that were created independently using the same values will be considered equal using == but not === because they are different objects. ([Source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/whats-the-difference-between-equalsequals-and-equalsequalsequals))

It would be worth it to read more on these operators from Swift's documentation.

Answer (score 16):

in **Swift 4.2**

**.index(where:)** was changed to **.firstIndex(where:)**

```
array.firstIndex(where: {$0 == "person1"})
```

Answer (score 15):

For custom class, you need to implement the Equatable protocol.

```
import Foundation

func ==(l: MyClass, r: MyClass) -> Bool {
  return l.id == r.id
}

class MyClass: Equtable {
    init(id: String) {
        self.msgID = id
    }

    let msgID: String
}

let item = MyClass(3)
let itemList = [MyClass(1), MyClass(2), item]
let idx = itemList.indexOf(item)

printl(idx)
```

Answer (score 13):

Just use firstIndex method.

```
array.firstIndex(where: { $0 == searchedItem })
```

Comment: Error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Element' operands

Answer (score 10):

**Update for Swift 2:**

> **sequence.contains(element)**: Returns true if a given sequence (such as
>   an array) contains the specified element.

**Swift 1:**

If you're looking just to check if an element is contained inside an array, that is, just get a boolean indicator, use `contains(sequence, element)` instead of `find(array, element)`:

> **contains(sequence, element)**: Returns true if a given sequence (such as
>   an array) contains the specified element.

See example below:

```
var languages = ["Swift", "Objective-C"]
contains(languages, "Swift") == true
contains(languages, "Java") == false
contains([29, 85, 42, 96, 75], 42) == true
if (contains(languages, "Swift")) {
  // Use contains in these cases, instead of find.   
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Swift 4. If your array contains elements of type [String: AnyObject]. So to find the index of element use the below code

```
var array = [[String: AnyObject]]()// Save your data in array
let objectAtZero = array[0] // get first object
let index = (self.array as NSArray).index(of: objectAtZero)
```

Or If you want to found index on the basis of key from Dictionary. Here array contains Objects of Model class and I am matching id property.

```
   let userId = 20
    if let index = array.index(where: { (dict) -> Bool in
           return dict.id == userId // Will found index of matched id
    }) {
    print("Index found")
    }
OR
      let storeId = Int(surveyCurrent.store_id) // Accessing model key value
      indexArrUpTo = self.arrEarnUpTo.index { Int($0.store_id) == storeId }! // Array contains models and finding specific one
```

Answer (score 7):

For `(>= swift 4.0)`

It's rather very simple.
Consider the following `Array` object.

```
var names: [String] = ["jack", "rose", "jill"]
```

In order to obtain the index of the element `rose`, all you have to do is:

```
names.index(of: "rose") // returns 1
```

**Note:**

- `Array.index(of:)` returns an `Optional<Int>`.
- `nil` implies that the element isn't present in the array.
- You might want to force-unwrap the returned value or use an `if-let` to get around the optional.

Answer (score 6):

In **Swift 4**, if you are traversing through your DataModel array, make sure your data model conforms to Equatable Protocol , implement the lhs=rhs method , and only then you can use ".index(of" . For example

```
class Photo : Equatable{
    var imageURL: URL?
    init(imageURL: URL){
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }

    static func == (lhs: Photo, rhs: Photo) -> Bool{
        return lhs.imageURL == rhs.imageURL
    }
}
```

And then,

```
let index = self.photos.index(of: aPhoto)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 2 (with Xcode 7), `Array` includes an [`indexOf`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2906763-index) method provided by the [`CollectionType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) protocol. (Actually, two `indexOf` methods—one that uses equality to match an argument, and [another](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2906873-index) that uses a closure.)

Prior to Swift 2, there wasn't a way for generic types like collections to provide methods for the concrete types derived from them (like arrays). So, in Swift 1.x, "index of" is a global function... And it got renamed, too, so in Swift 1.x, that global function is called `find`.

It's also possible (but not necessary) to use the `indexOfObject` method from `NSArray`... or any of the other, more sophisticated search meth dis from Foundation that don't have equivalents in the Swift standard library. Just `import Foundation` (or another module that transitively imports Foundation), cast your `Array` to `NSArray`, and you can use the many search methods on `NSArray`.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 2.1**

```
var array = ["0","1","2","3"]

if let index = array.indexOf("1") {
   array.removeAtIndex(index)
}

print(array) // ["0","2","3"]
```

**Swift 3**

```
var array = ["0","1","2","3"]

if let index = array.index(of: "1") {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
array.remove(at: 1)
```

Comment: you are mutating a ``let array``? The use of ``self`` is questionable also.

Answer (score 5):

Any of this solution works for me

This the solution i have for Swift 4 :

```
let monday = Day(name: "M")
let tuesday = Day(name: "T")
let friday = Day(name: "F")

let days = [monday, tuesday, friday]

let index = days.index(where: { 
            //important to test with === to be sure it's the same object reference
            $0 === tuesday
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the functional library Dollar to do an indexOf on an array as such http://www.dollarswift.org/#indexof-indexof

```
$.indexOf([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], value: 2) 
=> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are still working in Swift 1.x

then try,

```
let testArray = ["A","B","C"]

let indexOfA = find(testArray, "A") 
let indexOfB = find(testArray, "B")
let indexOfC = find(testArray, "C")
```

Answer (score 3):

For SWIFT 3 you can use a simple function

```
func find(objecToFind: String?) -> Int? {
   for i in 0...arrayName.count {
      if arrayName[i] == objectToFind {
         return i
      }
   }
return nil
}
```

This will give the number position, so you can use like

```
arrayName.remove(at: (find(objecToFind))!)
```

Hope to be useful

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4/5, use "firstIndex" for find index.

```
let index = array.firstIndex{$0 == value}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

For reference types:

```
extension Array where Array.Element: AnyObject {

    func index(ofElement element: Element) -> Int? {
        for (currentIndex, currentElement) in self.enumerated() {
            if currentElement === element {
                return currentIndex
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody has this problem

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Array<Element>.Index?)'
```

jsut do this

```
extension Int {
    var toInt: Int {
        return self
    }
}
```

then

```
guard let finalIndex = index?.toInt else {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4**

Let's say you want to store a number from the array called cardButtons into cardNumber, you can do it this way:

```
let cardNumber = cardButtons.index(of: sender)
```

sender is the name of your button