# How can I find the index of an item in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is there a method called indexof or something similar?

```
var array = ["Jason", "Charles", "David"]

indexOf(array, "Jason") // Should return 0
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

EDIT: As of Swift 3.0, you should use the `.index(where:)` method instead and follow the change in the Swift 2.0 edit below.

EDIT: As of Swift 2.0, you should use the `indexOf` method instead. It too returns `nil` or the first index of its argument.

```
if let i = array.indexOf("Jason") {
    print("Jason is at index \(i)")
} else {
    print("Jason isn't in the array")
}
```

Use the `find` function. It returns either `nil` (if the value isn't found) or the first index of the value in the array.

```
if let i = find(array, "Jason") {
    println("Jason is at index \(i)")
} else {
    println("Jason isn't in the array")
}
```

Comment: note: find works with any type of object in array of same type of objects ...

Comment: `find` no longer works for arrays in Swift 2.0

Comment: @kakubei thanks, updated

Comment: .index(where:) throws an error for me and I can't find reference to it anywhere. Shouldn't it be .index(of:)?

Comment: @nathan @Stonetip `index(of:)` is for finding an element that is `Equatable`, `index(where:)` requires a predicate and thus works for any collection.

Comment: @tim Thanks for the clarification. Your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351213/replacement-for-arrays-indexof-method-in-swift-3 explains it well.

Answer (score 14):

In Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.1b), you can use

```
if let result = array.indexOf("Jason")
```

while `find(array, "Jason")` is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

I made this function like above, but it return array of indexes

```
extension Array {
    func indexesOf<T : Equatable>(object:T) -> [Int] {
        var result: [Int] = []
        for (index,obj) in enumerate(self) {
            if obj as T == object {
                result.append(index)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Maybe it will be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Array can be bridged to an NSArray, so you can use:

```
array.bridgeToObjectiveC().indexOfObject("Jason")
```

Comment: `bridgeToObjectiveC()` is a private method. Use the `as` operator instead.

Comment: i.e. (array as NSArray).indexOfObject("Jason")

Answer (score 1):

An extension of Array can work wonders here. Here's an implementation shared in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029119/2228559):

```
extension Array {
  func find (includedElement: T -> Bool) -> Int? {
    for (idx, element) in enumerate(self) {
      if includedElement(element) {
        return idx
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Swift 2.0 has array.indexOf(...) so this is no longer needed

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Array Extension that does exactly what you want, i.e:

```
extension Array {
    func indexOf<T : Equatable>(x:T) -> Int? {
        for i in 0..self.count {
            if self[i] as T == x {
                return i
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Which now lets you use `.indexOf()` on all Swift arrays, e.g:

```
["Jason", "Charles", "David"].indexOf("Jason")  //0
```

Comment: This works like Charm!

Answer (score 0):

While the response from Max is great, it does not let you find multiple indexes of multiple objects, ie. indexes of the subset of the array. If you need that functionality, extensions are, as always, your best friend

```
func indexesOfSubset<T : Equatable>(objects : [T]) -> [Int] {

    // Create storage for filtered objectsand results
    var unusedObjects = objects
    var result : [Int] = []

    // Enumerate through all objects in array
    for (index, obj) in enumerate(self) {

        // Enumerate again through all objects that has not been found
        for x in unusedObjects {

            // If we hit match, append result, remove it from usused objects
            if obj as! T == x {
                result.append(index)
                unusedObjects = unusedObjects.filter( { $0 != x } )
                break
            }
        }
    }

    // Get results
    return result
}
```

Note* : Works on Swift 1.2, if you want compatibility with 1.1, replace as! -> as