# Replacement for array's indexOf(_:) method in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

In my project (written in Swift 3) I want to retrieve index of an element from array using `indexOf(_:)` method (existed in Swift 2.2), but I cannot find any replacement for that.

Is there any good replacement for that method in Swift 3 or anything that act similar?

**Update**

I forget to mention that I want to search in custom object. In code completion I haven't got any hints when typing 'indexof'. But when I try to get index of build in type like `Int` code completion works and I could use `index(of:)` method.

Comment: `index(of:)` ? Different syntax, same functionality. Suggestion: Use code-completion.

Comment: You need to read and bookmark this document: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md

Comment: Yeah I tried. But code completion didn't show `index(of:)` method for custom object. It shows only for build in types.

Comment: Your object has to conform to Equatable. I have an example here: stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`indexOf(_:)` has been renamed to `index(of:)` for types that conform to `Equatable`. You can conform any of your types to `Equatable`, it's not just for built-in types:

```
struct Point: Equatable {
    var x, y: Int
}

func == (left: Point, right: Point) -> Bool {
    return left.x == right.x && left.y == right.y
}

let points = [Point(x: 3, y: 5), Point(x: 7, y: 2), Point(x: 10, y: -4)]
points.index(of: Point(x: 7, y: 2)) // 1
```

`indexOf(_:)` that takes a closure has been renamed to `index(where:)`:

```
[1, 3, 5, 4, 2].index(where: { $0 > 3 }) // 2

// or with a training closure:
[1, 3, 5, 4, 2].index { $0 > 3 } // 2
```

Comment: Equatable matters :).

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work for me in Swift 3 XCode 8 until I gave my class an [extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable).

**For example:**

```
class MyClass {
    var key: String?
}

extension MyClass: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return MyClass.key == MyClass.key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Swift 3 without an extension:

```
struct MyClass: Equatable {
    let title: String

    public static func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
}
```