# Get index of object from outlet collection

Tags: ios, swift

In my UIViewController I've got outlet collection:

```
@IBOutlet var cardButtons: Array<UIButton>
```

Form this collection I want to get a index of object, but Array don't have a proper method for this. I found that 'indexOfObject' method is only in NSArray.

For now a I cast cardButtons property to NSArray

```
var cardButtonsArray = cardButtons as NSArray
```

and this solve my problem, but maybe there is another, more clean way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I googled 'indexOfObject in swift' for you. The top link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-apples-swift

Answer (score 0):

`firstIndex` is a method you can use on a Swift Array that returns the first element's index that matches the object you pass in:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex

```
func getIndexOf(button: UIButton) -> Int? {
    let buttonIndex = cardButtons.firstIndex(of: button)
    return buttonIndex
}
```