# How to find index of Int element in an array?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a "better"(less verbose) way of doing this?

```
var found: Int?  
for i in 0...myArray-1 {
    if myArray[i] == 3 {
        found = i
    }
}
```

similar to

```
let i = find(myArray, "1")
```

but for Int ?

This question is slightly "different" than [How to find index of list item in Apple's swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-apples-swift) because it directly address the find function for Int, instead of String.  Granted, the only difference is the title and pointing out that you can remove the quotation marks to get Int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an Int example

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3]
var i = find(myArray, 2)
```

Good luck

Comment: omg, sorry, but thank you ! working two timezones !

Comment: what do you mean by "working two timezones"? :)

Comment: find returns an optional so you should use if let i = find(myArray,2) {...}

Comment: "Timezones": US and Europe