# Array does not perform a command in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

Array does not perform a command in swift

I show a simple example

```
    var array = ["x", "y", "z"]
    var index = array.indexOf("y")
```

I get an error 
*'[String]' does not have a member named 'indexOf'*

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-apples-swift) but it doesn't help me.

I imported

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import CoreAudio
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit
```

Comment: what swift version you use? my guess is that indexOf method appeared in swift 2.0

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you, my mistake I use Swift 1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

indexOf is only available in swift 2.0