# viewControllers indexOfObject in swift

Tags: ios, swift, indexof

I have this objective-c method that i'm trying to re-write to swift.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    int index = [navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    self.pageControl.currentPage = index;
}
```

I'm having difficulties writing this line in swift:

```
int index = [navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
```

How do i access the IndexOfObject?

Comment: In Swift 2.0 you could you the indexOf method, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24069331/3617012

Comment: How can i check what Swift version i am using?

Comment: If you are using Xcode 7 (not yet released officially), then you have Swift 2.0 at your fingertips. Xcode 6.4 supports Swift 1.2, and you would use the `find` function instead of `indexOf`. How to use it is also explained in the answer that I've linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.x)**

```
let index = find(navigationController.viewControllers, viewController)!
```

**In Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.x)**

```
let arrayOfVCs = navigationController.viewControllers as Array
let index = arrayOfVCs.indexOf(viewController)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4, for `TabBarController`, to get index of selected view controller:

```
let index = tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 5**  `index(of element: Element)` is deprecated .. so use

```
let index = navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: yourController)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0 (Xcode 8.x)**

```
let index = navigationController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)
```