# Swift find() method throwing error

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, segue

When i opened my app today, Xcode asked if i wanted to update some syntax. I followed through the update prompts and after all was said and done my app now has this error on one of the "find" methods. Ive been scratching my head over this one for about an hour now. Any advice on what might have changed?

[image: Error]

Comment: maybe you should post the code in question, the error you got, etc.

Comment: You updated Xcode to 7.x

Comment: Actually the error message tells you exactly what to do

Comment: @vadian like this? `if let index = indexOf(playlistArray, playlistImageView) `

Comment: `method calling on object` means `object.method()`, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069331/1217087), Swift 2.0 removed the `find` method and replaced it with `indexOf` (as indicated by the error Xcode is giving you).

You can fix your code as follows:

```
if let index = playlistArray.indexOf(playlistImageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully. It says

`find(haystack, needle)` is unavailable, call `haystack.indexOf(needle)`