# How to find index of a value from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Suppose I am `searching for cardType = points`, if its found I want to know the index position of that object. According to the given example array, index position of this object is 1. Below is the example array.

```
[{
cardCode = MGC;
cardId = 5720663d8944bf6710c9d894;
cardType = gift;
},
{
cardCode = MPC;
cardId = 5720663d8944bf6710c9d898;
cardType = points;
}, 
{
cardCode = MAC;
cardId = 5720663d8944bf6710c9d895;
cardType = advantage;
},
{
cardCode = MCC;
cardId = 5720663d8944bf6710c9d897;
cardType = cashback;
}]
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Both question are different. I not accecing the array which contain element of type String. The answer based on the method `index(of)` which is not available in my case.

Comment: Did you read *all* answers of that Q&A? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24069331/1187415 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32923407/1187415 both explain how to use `index(where: ..)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index) for that.

```
if let index = yourArray.index(where: { $0.cardType == "points" }) {
    print(index) //1
}
```

Comment: crashing with error message, found nil. But my array has the value.

Comment: @KunalKumar Edit you question with your new code and add screen shot with error.

Comment: Everything is same as described in the question.

Comment: @KunalKumar If it is all describe that you will not get nil. Where you are getting this nil?

Comment: something strange is happening, the line in question getting executed two times. first time it gives correct value, second time throwing error.

Comment: @KunalKumar You are force wrapping your array, may be it is nil. try like this way `if let array = selectedCard, let index = array.index(where: { $0.cardType == "points" }) {
    print(index) //1
}` Also in question you have asked to compare for `points` and you are comparing `advantage`

Comment: Again same, don't know whats wrong. I think "points" or "advantage" is not the problem. It should have work with any

Comment: btw selected card is an array or a dictionary ? if it is an array of dictionaries  `if let index = arrayDict.index(where: { $0["cardType"] == "points" }) {`

Comment: @KunalKumar Can you add the declaration of `selectedCard` array?

Comment: selectedCard is array `var selectedCard:[AnyObject]?` Its getting populated with network response.

Comment: @KunalKumar How does `AnyObject` have property `cardType`?

Comment: I think AnyObject can store any type of data.

Comment: I am logging the selectedCard array to check if it has value or not.

Comment: @KunalKumar Your `selectedCard` array contains dictionary as object or custom class object?

Comment: Dictionary as object

Comment: Then try like this way `if let array = selectedCard, let index = array.index(where: { $0["cardType"] as? String ?? "" == "points" }) { print(index) //1 }`

Comment: worked :) can you update your answer with little explanation.

Comment: @KunalKumar On of your dictionary in your array have nil value or key is not exist so that you are getting crash.