# Find custom Object index in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of custom object called `Service` and in `didSelectRow` I populate my selected array of that object:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        let services:[Service] = self.menu[indexPath.section].services
        self.selectedServices.append(services[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to retrieve it from didDeselectRow:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
        let services = self.menu[indexPath.section].services
        let service = services[indexPath.row]
        //how can I found the index position of service inside selectedServices?

    }

}
```

Comment: selectedServices[indexPath.row] how about

Comment: Have you tried self.selectedServices[indexPath.row] ?

Comment: No please read the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you don't store the `selectedServices`, but rely on [`UITableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows).

```
var selectedServices: [Service] {
    let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? []
    return indexPaths.map { self.menu[$0.section].services[$0.row] }
}
```

This way, you don't need to manually maintain `selectedServices` and could remove the entire `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` function.

---

If you must maintain a separate state, you could find the service using [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/defaultindices/1784703-index) or `index(of:)` — see [How to find index of list item in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift).

```
if let i = (self.selectedServices.index { $0 === service }) {
// find the index `i` in the array which has an item identical to `service`.
    self.selectedServices.remove(at: i)
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's an answer ;)