# Find index of objects array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I can't figure out how to find index of object in array. For example I have this data structure:

```
class Person {
var name: String
var age: Int

init(name personName: String, age personAge: Int) {
    self.name = personName
    self.age = personAge
  }
}

let person1 = Person(name: "person1", age: 34)
let person2 = Person(name: "person2", age: 30)
...
var personsArray = [person1, person2, ...]
```

I tried to use `personsArray.index(where: ....)` but I don't understand how to use it. `index(of: ...)` doesn't work. I think because `personsArray` doesn't conform to `Equatable` protocol...

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/32923407/1187415 if you want to find the identical object.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
index(of: )
```

gets the Person in your case - it is generic function.

```
index(where: )
```

gets the condition for which you want to find particular Person

What you could do:

```
personsArray.index(where: { $0.name == "person1" })
```

Or you could send object to:

```
personsArray.index(of: existingPerson)
```

For both options you could get nil - you will have to check it for nil (or guard it).

Comment: `index(of: )` doen't compile ( . Thanks for sharing, I will use `(where: $0.name == ...)`

Comment: Don't forget {} for where and for index(of: ) You need to provide actual object of the array

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view just compare with `===`.

Small example.

```
func getPersonIndex(from: [Person], user: Person) -> Int? {
    return from.index(where: { $0 === user })
}

getPersonIndex(from: personsArray, user: person2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to use `.index(where...`

`personsArray.index { (item) -> Bool in
    item.name == "person2" && item.age == 30
}`