# Find an item index using two collection type arguments

Tags: swift

I have checked this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift) to find a solution for the deprecated `find` method, but the solution is for single array. In my project I am have two arguments that are both collection types. Through refactoring I am receiving the familiar conditional binding errors.

I have tried removing the conditional binding and using `index(of: )` as in the SO answer I referenced, but since I'm not working with single elements like String types naturally I get tuple errors.

If methods can't be called on tuples why was the original `find` method able to call the tuple in the Swift 2 line below?

```
class MoneyPickerTableViewController: UITableViewController {   

var money: [String: String]
var purchaseOrder: [String]
var chosenKey: String = USDPreferences.shared().object(forKey: kUSDChosenMoneyKey) as! String    

// Swift 2
if let index = find(purchaseOrder, chosenKey) {
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)

tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: animated, scrollPosition: .Middle)
}    

navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Swift 3

```
let collections = (purchaseOrder, chosenKey) as ([String], String) 
let index = collections.index(of: )
```

Comment: You can't call methods on tuples and just expect that the method is applied to each tuple member. That's just not how Swift works

Comment: Thanks. I realize that. That's why I said "naturally I'm getting these errors". I am looking for a way to index the two collections. The original code was indexing fine using `find(purchaseOrder, chosenKey)`. p.s the `find` method was fine with the tuple before so why not now?

Comment: that's not a tuple, it's a function call containing two arguments `purchaseOrder` and `chosenKey`.

Comment: Ok I understand because of the `find` method it is a function call. And now there is no function call so it is a tuple. I have to make it a function call again using `index(of:` ).

Comment: Yes. see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`find(_:_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v1.2/func/find/) used to be a free function that took a Collection as its first argument, and the desired element as the second.

Since Swift 2, this functionality is now implemented as an instance method on Collection, called [`index(of:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/protocol/Collection/#func-iterator-element_-equatable-index-of_).

What used to be `find(purchaseOrder, chosenKey)` is now spelled `purchaseOrder.index(of: chosenKey)`

Comment: `collections` isn't a collection. It's a tuple containing a `[String]` and a `[String]`... See my edit

Comment: `index = purchseOrder(of: chosenKey)` gives me a `Cannot call value of non-function type '[String]?'` error. Obviously since `purchaseOrder` is not a function type.

Comment: @tymac That was a typo, it was supposed to be `purchaseOrder.index(of: chosenKey)`. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Your `Swift3` attempt has nothing to do with your `Swift2` code.
In the `Swift2` code, `find(purchaseOrder, chosenKey)` returns the index of the String variable, `chosenKey` in an array of Strings, `purchaseOrder`. In your `Swift3` code you are trying make a tuple from your array of strings and from your search string and look up the elements in a tuple, which will never work, since you are trying to search a tuple with a non-tuple value.

In reality the code should be this simple: you just need to find the index of `chosenKey` in `purchaseOrder` using the `index(of:)` function and use that as the `row` index.

```
guard let row = purchaseOrder.index(of: chosenKey) else { return }
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: animated, scrollPosition: .middle)
```

Comment: Please advise the etiquette here guys. Alexander gave me the answer first but it needed a simple edit I should've been able to spot, while David's answer was the complete answer including bonus guard. Gulp.

Comment: Well, it's your choice whose answer you accept, choose the one you felt helped you more. If both answers helped, you can up vote both anyways :)

Comment: Sorry David. I had to give it to Alex because he had already laid out all the ground work. I gave you an upvote obviously because I ended up using your guard. I would normally give you the correct answer because you gave all the complete code for it but this case was different.