# Find NSTableView cell with substring and scroll to cell

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I have a 100mb log file that I separate by line and set as an NSArray. After I display the text in a NSTableView.

I want to be able to select a certain substring, find which cell has the substring and scroll to the cell.

What I have so far:

This is the array that holds the text from the 100mb log file separated by line.

```
var linesArray: NSArray = []
```

This is the substring that I want to find, keep in mind it is a substring. So the line may have other text in it.

```
var testSearchTerm: String = "1970-01-02"
```

I am able to find all the lines with the value, but it returns the line and I need the index so I can scroll to the index.

```
let filteredStrings = linesArray.filter { (item) -> Bool in

        let asString = item as! String
        var stringMatch = asString.range(of: testSearchTerm)
        return stringMatch != nil ? true : false

    }
```

How do I get the index from the function above, also is it possible to find the first instance of the substring, not all. Right now it gets every instance of the substring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of list item in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift)

Comment: Is this a question about `NSTableView`?