# How to convert Array of Months Name to Months Number in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my project, I am selecting months from picker view that month name is placed in Text field. But I have to send Month Number to the server.

This is my month array

```
var monthsArray = ["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"]
```

Here I am getting a problem. For an example If I select April, I have to send 4 to the server, How to do this task please someone help/ advise me.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function like this may help

```
func getMonthIndex(_ month: String) -> Int {
    let months = ["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"]
    var monthIndex = -1
    if let idx = months.index(of: month.uppercased()) {
        monthIndex = idx + 1
    }
    return monthIndex
}
```

which can be used as follows :

```
var idx = getMonthIndex("January")  //1
idx = getMonthIndex("JANUARY") //1
idx = getMonthIndex("DECEMBER") //12
idx = getMonthIndex("DECEMBERRRR") //-1
```

In the snipped above "month.uppercased()" is very important this will help to identify months in all cases such as "January", "JANUARY" OR "january"

Comment: I think this answer must be selected. because in this answer accept all type of string  And reuse that function at any time.

Comment: Yeah i will accept this ans its working for me

Answer (score 2):

If you have the text value, just find the index of that value in the array and then add 1 (because the array is zero index based)

Something like this should work:

```
var monthsArray = ["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"]
if let index = monthsArray.index(of: "APRIL") { // index will be 3 (zero based)
    let monthNumber = index + 1 // +1 as explained earlier
    print(monthNumber) // output: 4
}
```