# How can I write down a shortened if condition?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Does anyone have an idea how to write the following code in a shortened form?

```
if self.atPoint(locationUser) == blueMarkArray[0] || self.atPoint(locationUser) == blueMarkArray[1] || self.atPoint(locationUser) == blueMarkArray[2] || self.atPoint(locationUser) == blueMarkArray[3] || self.atPoint(locationUser) == blueMarkArray[4] || self.atPoint(locationUser) == blueMarkArray[5] || self.atPoint(locationUser) == blueMarkArray[6]{

            print("its here")
        }
```

Furthermore, I don't want to commit myself to a fixed number of elements in the `blueMarkArray` array. It **should be as variable** as possible, because for example it can contain 4 elements, but also 12 elements.

For each answer I am very grateful.

**EDIT:**

How can you access the found element if I want to write the following: `someNode.position = elementOfMarkArray.position`

Comment: This is probably not a duplicate as I don't think you want to be testing if a point is in the list in that manner, due to floating point precision issues.  You probably want to test if the point is *near* one of these points by calculating their distance.

Comment: Your added question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069331.

Comment: @MartinR I believe you are wrong marking this question as just another *find-in-list* issue.  Please vote to re-open.

Comment: @trojanfoe: As I understand it, OP asks how to shorten the comparison against multiple array elements, or how to find its position in an array. That has been asked and answered before. – It *might* be better to find the “nearest” array element, but that is not what is asked here.

Comment: @MartinR Agreed the OP has not asked the question correctly; as well as being unaware of the nuisances of collection classes etc, they appear to lack understanding of 2D graphics.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Haven't seen you here for a while – welcome back!

Comment: @MartinR Yeah it's been a while.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array's `contains` method

```
if (blueMarkArray.contains(self.atPoint(locationUser))) {
   //
}
```

or, if you need to check only up to index `6` like in your example, use

```
if (blueMarkArray[0...6].contains(self.atPoint(locationUser))) {
   //
}
```

if you want to get the index of the element, you can use `firstIndex` of `lastIndex` methods

```
if let index = blueMarkArray.firstIndex(of: self.atPoint(locationUser)) {
   //
}
```

Comment: It works, but how can you access the found element if I want to write the following: `someNode.position = elementOfMarkArray.position`

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Your first and second example are the same, the second doesn't actually check only up to index 6. There's also no need to use parentheses for the condition of an `if` statement in Swift, unlike in Objective-C (and the common pattern is not to use them).

Comment: @DávidPásztor an error during edit, now corrected

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't quite understand how to use `index`. Unfortunately it doesn't work that way: `if let index = blueMarkArray.firstIndex(of: self.atPoint(locationUser) as! SKSpriteNode) {
                    someNode.position = index.position
                }`

Comment: I got it and it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use the `contains` method of `Array`, which will return true if any of the elements of the array equals `self.atPoint(locationUser)`.

```
if blueMarkArray.contains(self.atPoint(locationUser)) {
    print("it's here")
}
```

If you also need to access the element that matches the object/value you are looking for, you can use `first(where:)` or `firstIndex(of:)`.

```
if let location = blueMarkArray.first(where: {$0 == self.atPoint(locationUser)}) {
    someNode.position = location.position
}
```

or

```
if let locationIndex = blueMarkArray.firstIndex(of: self.atPoint(locationUser)) {
   let location = blueMarkArray[locationIndex]
   someNode.position = location.position
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array's` method `contains`:

```
if blueMarkArray.contains(self.atPoint(locationUser)) {
    print("its here")
}
```