# How to get the positions of an element in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a question and I hope that one of you can help me: I need to find the *positions* of an element in an array. 
For example:

```
var elements: [String] = ["a","b","c","a","c"]
var element = "a"
```

I need to know in what positions is the element, in this case `0,3`
I have tried with some nested for loops but it was a mess, can you help me? 
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift may be a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var elements: [String] = ["a","b","c","a","c"]
var element = "a"
let indexes = elements.enumerated().compactMap { index, elem -> Int? in
  guard elem == element else { return nil }
  return index
}
print(indexes) // It will print [0, 3]
```

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate. No need to post an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I know that. I was writing it while you closed it and didn't notice.

Comment: @FrancescoMattiussi you can simply filter your collection indices  `elements.indices.filter({elements[$0] == element})`